# How to move a SVG element after I create it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I create a mini SVG editor and now I have the following problem. How can I move an element after I created it?

I want to select the element with left-click and then onMouseDown event to move the element.

Here is my html code:

```js
    function inspect(obj) {
        var str = new Array();
        var element = null;
        for(element in obj) { str[str.length] = element; }
        str.sort();
        alert(obj + ":" + str.join(' '));
    }
    
    var bMouseDragging = false;
    var nMouseOffsetX = 0;
    var nMouseOffsetY = 0;
    var background = document.getElementById('background');
    
    function mouseDown(evt) { 
        bMouseDragging = true;

        var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
        if(ball) {
            var p = document.documentElement.createSVGPoint();
            p.x = evt.clientX;
            p.y = evt.clientY;
        
            var m = ball.getScreenCTM();
            p = p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());
            nMouseOffsetX = p.x - parseInt(ball.getAttribute('cx'));
            nMouseOffsetY = p.y - parseInt(ball.getAttribute('cy'));
        }
    }
    function mouseUp(evt) { 
        bMouseDragging = false;
    }
    function mouseMove(evt) { 

        var p = document.documentElement.createSVGPoint();
        p.x = evt.clientX;
        p.y = evt.clientY;
        var bClient = true;
        
        if(bMouseDragging) {
            var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
            if(ball) {
        
                var m = ball.getScreenCTM();
                p = p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());

                ball.setAttribute('cx', p.x - nMouseOffsetX);
                ball.setAttribute('cy', p.y - nMouseOffsetY);
                bClient = false;
            }
        }
        
        displayCoords(p.x, p.y, (bClient ? " (client)" : " (svg user)"));
    }
    
    function displayCoords(x,y,extra) {
        var xNode = document.getElementById('xpos');
        var yNode = document.getElementById('ypos');
        if(xNode && yNode) {
            xNode.firstChild.nodeValue = parseInt(x) + extra;
            yNode.firstChild.nodeValue = parseInt(y) + extra;
        }
    }
    
    function displayRawText(text) {
        var textNode = document.getElementById('raw');
        if(textNode) {
            textNode.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
        }
    }
    
    function init() {
        var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
        if(ball) {
            ball.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
            ball.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
            ball.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
        }
        displayRawText("Drag the ball around");
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SVG Editor</title>
    <link href="svg_editor.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--                            JQUERY SCRIPTS                                      -->
    <script src="jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.svg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script scr="jquery.svg.input.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.transit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="svg_editor">
        <h1>
            SVG Editor
        </h1>
        <div id="workspace">
            <svg id="svg">
                <svg id="elements"></svg>
                <line id="line" style="display:normal" stroke="red" fill="red"></line>
                <rect id="rectangular" width="1" height="1" fill="transparent" stroke="green" 
                     style="fill-opacity:0.1" ></rect>
                <ellipse rx="1" ry="1" cx="1" cy="1" id="ellipse" style="stroke:red ; fill:none" transform="translate(0,0)"></ellipse>
             
                    <foreignObject id="x" x="1" y="1" width="1" height="1" style="display:normal" stroke="orange" fill="green" visibillity="hidden">
                        <textArea id="textArea" rows="1" cols="1" border="1px" font-size="14" font-family="Arial" stroke="blue"
                                  transform="translate(18,18)">
                            Type the text here...
                        </textArea>
                    </foreignObject>
              
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>   


    <div id="toolbox" class="tools_panel">

        <div class="tool_button" id="select_tool" title="Select Tool [S]" style="margin: 4px 4px 8px;">
            <img class="svg_icon" 
                 src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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" />
        </div>

        <div class="tool_button" id="line_tool" title="Draw Line Tool [L]" data-curopt="#tool_line"
             style="margin: 4px 4px 8px;">
            <img class="svg_icon" 
                 src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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" />
        </div>

        <div class="tool_button" id="rectangular_tool" title="Draw Rectangular Tool [R]" data-curopt="#tool_rect"
             style="margin: 4px 4px 8px;" >
            <img class="svg_icon" 
                 src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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" />
        </div>

        <div class="tool_button" id="ellipse_tool" title="Draw Ellipse Tool [E]" data-curopt="#tool_ellipse"
             style="margin: 4px 4px 8px;" >
            <img class="svg_icon"
                 src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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" />
        </div>

        <div class="tool_button" id="text_tool" title="Text Area Tool [T]" data-curopt="#tool_text" 
             style="margin:4px 4px 8px;">
            <img class="svg_icon"
                 src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(svgEditor);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I ask for an example of how to move an object that is just created. I search and I find only examples of how to move a static SVG element.

Comment: stick a transform on the element.

Comment: I want to select it with left click and after that to drag it where I want.